# How to setup Unity in MonoTouch/MonoDroid application?

Tags: android, ios, mono, unity-game-engine

Good evening, folks.

I need to have ability to develop in Xamarin Studio Android/iOS apps, but with ability to setup Unity inside them. I actually I dont know how. (Im monotouch/monodroid developer and I dont know what is Unity. I know that it uses mono, but modified mono, not original) Could you helo me with this question?
So... How Unity works? Where is mono in Unity? What do I need to do to setup Unity as part of monotouch/monodroid UI?

Answer (score 0):

Had same idea and did some search recently. Basically the answer is no. Because Unity embeds Mono runtime as scripting engine, and it's not possible to run two different instances of the Mono runtime inside a single process.

Hope the following links can help:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7095/unity-3d-integration-how-to

http://www.mono-project.com/Scripting_With_Mono

Comment: Actually we got working sample code. This feature possible if you carefully edit with your own console application all imports and exports tables in your app and Unity3D's mono to make all functions names different with Xamarin mono (For example, they should be generated). We got xamarin and Unity3d inside it. But after launching big sample, it failed to start. It was just beacuse we make 'dirty' replacement of unity functions names. Project wasn't release because this solution wasn't stable.

Comment: Hi Alexus, Thanks for update! It seems you partly find the solution. Your project is on Android, iOS or both? Do you use Android Library Project / Binding Java Library or Binding Objective-C? What's the best 3D solution for Xamarin(MonoTouch/MonoDroid) besides Unity, any suggestion?